# Failed to load today extension on device

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

iOS8. Today's extension. Trying to create simple table view with few rows (2-5). Runs fine in Simulator. Memory usage after tableView is loaded and shown ~30M according to Xcode profiler.

When running same extension on iPhone 5S with the latest beta drop (5) - tableView would appear and immediately disappear from the screen. Console log in Xcode shows lots of "memory warning" messages. After couple attempts to load extension panel would just display "Failed to load".

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The memory pressure I was experiencing on the device was due to using custom fonts. I had one `otf` font that I was embedding inside the widget binary (file size 136k btw), and that along was adding ~10M to the memory footprint. After removing custom font - everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is a really helpful one. Solved my issue. Thaanks again